# SecurityAgent pop-up does not get to window 1 (or any for that matter)

Tags: popup, passwords, window, applescript

I am writing some simple apps using AppleScript for my own need. I should say I am a total noob still trying to make sense of the various elements of code.

When trying to enable a service, let's say to turn the server on using scripted UI actions, any other time, a Security Agent popup occurs. In order to automate the action, I have written the following piece of code:

the 1st bit is to check whether the Server is already ON and if not click the button to turn it on (it works):

```
    tell application "ServerActivator" to activate
    try
tell application "System Events"
        tell process "ServerActivator"
            if text field 1 of group "IP Config" of tab group 1 of window "Server Activator" is enabled then click button "ON" of window "Server Activator"
        end tell
    end tell
on error errMsg
end try
```

the second bit is to put fill the SecurityAgent pop up with the password

```
    try
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "SecurityAgent"
            activate
            set value of text field "Password :" of window 1 to "myPassword"
            click button 2 of window 1
        end tell
    end tell
on error errMsg
end try
```

The second bit does not work properly as the code usually returns that windows 1 does not exist. However should I manually click on the window when the SecurityAgent popup appears, then and only then the code works. Obviously I want this to work independently of any user action. Any idea?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: The `activate` _command_ has no affect on a `process`! You can `activate` an `application`, but not a `process`.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know that. That will spare me some lines!

Answer (score 0):

Just wait until the process exists, the `try` block as well as the `activate` line is not needed.

```
tell application "System Events"
    repeat until exists window 1 of process "SecurityAgent"
        delay 0.5
    end repeat
    tell window 1 of process "SecurityAgent"
        set value of text field 1 to "myPassword"
        keystroke return
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to reply @vadian. However I still get the same error: **Error in system events : cannot get window 1 of process "SecurityAgent". Invalid index.**

Comment: Thanks again @vadian! Sadly, the event never happens and the script seems to run an endless loop (been running for 5 minutes now). I really do not understand what is happening : the app "VPN server" does prompt a SecurityAgent popup (and I can see the process in the activity monitor) but window 1 seems to never "exist" unless I manually click on it. I have tried countless methods, even setting an action to simulate a click on the screen where the popup is but nothing seems to work...

Comment: Strange. I'm using the code in several scripts without problems.

Comment: Indeed. I am starting to think the app itself has an issue. (The app is "VPNActivator" a Mac freeware to use the built-in VPN server in macOS.)

Comment: Using another app, the Code works fine. It suggests the issue I have encountered is linked with the way this particular app has been coded.